# Adding line breaks to absolutely positioned text blocks over images to create strips of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image that when rolled over reveals some lines of text, white on a red background. I would like there to be a break in the strips for each break in the line of text, like the image linked below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0LnR.jpg

However, all I've gotten to so far, is making the text appear in one single large red block. I would like the text to know where to break if it's too big for 80% of the image, and appear on a new line with a new red strip behind it.

Here's a fiddle of what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/mAU3d/

```
.thumb {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.text, .text-js {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px !important;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #999;
    background-color: #F63146;
    width:80%;
    padding: 1%;
    display: inline;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Sorry if the explanation is unclear, thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, all I've gotten to so far, is making the text appear in one single large red block.

That’s how block elements are rendered. (Your try to use `display:inline` is hindered by the use of absolute positioning, which automatically makes an element `block`.)

But you have an `h2` element inside the `div` – so make *that* `inline`. Sadly, you can not get padding on all sides of broken lines in an inline element – but if you just want a background-color for effect, you can fake that using a `box-shadow`.

```
.text-js h2 {
    display:inline;
    background: #F63146;
    box-shadow:-5px 0 #F63146, 5px 0 #F63146;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mAU3d/5/

Comment: perfect, thanks. And thanks for tip about the box shadow, it was something I was wondering about elsewhere on the site.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to set the `h2` display to `inline`. Then remove the background from the `.text-js` and add it to the `h2`. I also increased `line-height` to add some space between lines.

```css
.text-js h2 {
    display: inline;
    background: #F63146;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mAU3d/10/

Answer (score 0):

<s>I don't think it is necessary to use any fake box-shadow</s> (EDIT: box-shadow is actually useful, see the comments), you just need to style the text itself (i.e. using a span) rather than the block containing it (which is the h2):
http://jsfiddle.net/mastazi/M6APy/

```
<h2 class="text"><span class="break">Text should break in to new strips</span></h2>

.break{
    background-color: #F63146;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

Comment: Without the shadow there is no red space before and after each line.

Comment: I used the `box-shadow` to emulate the effect that `padding-left` and `-right` _would_ have on a single line of text. But once the text goes over multiple lines for an `inline` element, the padding is only applied before the first line and after the last line – and that’s likely not the desired effect here. `box-shadow` however applies to each of the lines in the same way.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't think about that.